# Configure nginx to access website without port in url

Tags: nginx, server

I have a CentOS 7 server and nginx running. If I start my next.js app on port `3000` and go to the ip address I see a welcome to nginx page. But If I go to `ip_address:3000` I see my actual website.

If I type my server's ip address to chrome `xxx.x.xxx.xx` I see welcome to nginx page

If I type my server's ip address and my application's port `xxx.x.xxx.xx:3000` I see my actual website.

my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;

   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   root /var/www/html;

   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

   server_name mydomain.com.tr www.mydomain.com.tr;

   location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
   }
}
```

After I modify my configuration file I type `sudo service nginx restart` to apply changes. But nothing changes. How can I access my website with only IP address?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but if you use the server_name directive with only the two domains, you are not able to access the website using the server's ip because it's not matching and therefore the proxy_pass is not used.

You can still access your app using the 3000 port because you don't use the 3000 port in your nginx config.

Comment: How can I use port 3000 in my config?